# How to dynamically assign class inside map in React with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new to React.
In one component of my `gatsby` site I have a list of `li` dynamically generated through a map. This list contains the taxonomies of the posts that I got from WP through graphQL.
I need to assign a specific class to the clicked `li`, in the following way:

- None on first render at all the `li`, then

  - `postlink-selected` at the clicked `li`
  - `post-link` at all the others non clicked `li`

With the code below I can get the behavior I need, but it works on the second click.
Reading several posts I understood that the issue is that I am reading the previous state, therefore I need the second click.
I also understood that i could fix this behavior by setting `useEffect`, I tried but unfortuntely in I was not able to set properly `useEffect` to get the desired behavior,  ( my attempts with `useEffect` are not reported in the code)

Here below the code that works on second click, I apologize if not very elegant. Most of the code is for other things like persisting some state in child component, but the focus is on the `setActiveId` in the `li` component as per the comment

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql, Link } from 'gatsby';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

const query = graphql`
   query {
  allWpPost {
    group(field: categories___nodes___name) {
      fieldValue
      edges {
        node {
          title
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;

const CategoryBar = ({ children }) => {
  const { allWpPost } = useStaticQuery(query);
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);
  const initialChoice = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.localStorage.getItem('choice') || 'projects' : null;
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState(initialChoice);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('choice', choice);
  }, [choice, setChoice]);
  return (
    <div className="mainList">
      <div className="entryList">
        <div className="content">
        <ul>
          {allWpPost.group.map((category, i) => (
            <li
              key={category.fieldValue.toString()}
              className={activeId === null ? ' ' : ((activeId === i) ? 'post-linkselected' : 'post-link')}
              onClick={() => setActiveId(i)} //here I set the state but it is read on second click
            >
              <Link
                to={`/${category.fieldValue.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}/${category.fieldValue.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}posts`}
                onClick={() => setChoice(parse(category.fieldValue.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()))}
                state={{ choice: parse(category.fieldValue.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()) }}
              >
                {category.fieldValue}
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryBar;
```

Many many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is gatsby Link's activeClassName.
Using this prop gatsby automatically adds your chosen className (postlink-selected in your case) to the Link component:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#add-custom-styles-for-the-currently-active-link

I'm not sure for what purpose you're using localStorage, but I'm guessing you're trying to navigate to the previously saved category page by default; If that's the case just setting the active class on the link will not suffice, you need to actually navigate the user to that page.

If you can clarify your intention I may be able to help furtuer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, activeClassName will apply the class to the active link but I need also to apply another class (post-link) to the rest of the links, diffferent from the blank class they have by default. So i though about the conditional form. I used local storage for a different purpose (i.e to persist a state in child component but that part works so it is fine)

Comment: `@AliTabatabaei` sorry i forgot to mention your username

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation my problem seems to be generated by the fact that on render of the child component the parent re-renders applying the initial state 'null' in `const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);`. This ovveride the state set by `onClick={() => setActiveId(i)` and the blank class is applied.
On second click on the same `li` instead the re-render does not happen and the state is updated correctly, applying the two classes as expected.
Any insight on how to fix this behavior?
Thanks a lot